# CSS - linear-gradient does not work in the background property

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a tree using `vue-orgchart` ([link](https://spiritree.github.io/vue-orgchart/#/))

It works fine, but I would like to change the green background of the node (ignore the white part).

[image]

The css can be found in the following [link](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-orgchart/dist/style.min.css).

I found out that the green color is: `#42b983`. So it easy to find it in the css file:

```
.orgchart .node .title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #42b983;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

And just change it:

```
background-color: linear-gradient(#66cccc, #3399cc);
```

But, for some reason, I get:

[image]

If I try to use any other color (without `linear-gradient`) it will be successful.

Also, I use this style (`linear-gradient`) in other parts of the web, and it works fine, so it isn't the problem with the browser (I use chrome if it matters).

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: gradient is an image not a color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please put below code

```
background-image: linear-gradient(#66cccc, #3399cc);
```